# Copying files from directory to another

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently writing a script that will basically ‘install’ a codeigniter installation automatically.

Basically I need to…

1. Create a new folder
2. Copy files from another folder and paste them into the newly created folder
3. Modify 2 config files within the new installation

I am using PHP but I am thinking I perhaps need to trigger another script in a server side language?

Also, I need advice on how I can trigger this script without hanging the browser (ie. redirect the user to a holding page that tells them to wait 5 or so minutes)as it will take quite a while for the 2000 files+ to be copied across.

I appreciate all your thoughts and suggestions.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: You might want to look into dedicated deployment tools like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd like to install CI from a server to a client's PC? Or from server to server?

For cross server copy, you can try [stream_copy_to_stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php).

If you don't want to hang the browser, you could use AJAX to trigger the copy in the source server asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to answer. Looks like this is what I'll have to do!